# Validate radio button input JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
const inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
const inputEmail = document.getElementById('input-email');
const button = document.querySelector('.submit-button');
const regEx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

function confirmInput() {
  var inputCycling = document.getElementById('input-cycling').checked;
  var inputRunning = document.getElementById('input-running').checked;
  var inputSwimming = document.getElementById('input-swimming').checked;
  if (
    inputName.value.trim() !== "" &&
    regEx.test(inputEmail.value) &&
    inputCycling == false &&
    inputRunning == false &&
    inputSwimming == false
  ) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#342e7d';
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#979797';
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(inputName.value + ' ' + inputEmail.value);
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="name" oninput="confirmInput()">
    <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" oninput="confirmInput()">
    <div id="radio-type">
      <input type="radio" id="input-cycling" name="sport" value="cycling" oninput="confirmInput()"> Cycling
      <input type="radio" id="input-running" name="sport" value="running" oninput="confirmInput()"> Running
      <input type="radio" id="input-swimming" name="sport" value="swimming" oninput="confirmInput()"> Swimming
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-button" disabled>
        Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have a function which validates my form, if valid then the button changes color and disabled set to false.

The name and the email validation works fine but I am having some issues with the radio button validation. I am following the same logic but just can't get it to work, maybe a fresh pair of eyes can see something I am missing.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. Include the relevant HTML. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Your code has a bunch of undefined variables in it

Comment: In my understanding the radiobutton in question has 3 choices and you demand all 3 of them are inactive? I thought the whole schtick of radiobuttons is that they're supposed to always have 1 choice selected as opposed to checkboxes.

Comment: that is probably not your production code as buttom...is not defined. Also you probably don't want to define these vars in a function

Comment: @Quentin I have updated the original post and also added the markup. Excuse my ignorance but where is the live demo feature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: thank you @Quentin, i have added the snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check1() {            
        var radio_check_val = "";
        for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('gender').length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementsByName('gender')[i].checked) {
                alert("this radio button was clicked: " + document.getElementsByName('gender')[i].value);
                radio_check_val = document.getElementsByName('gender')[i].value;        
            }        
        }
        if (radio_check_val === "")
        {
            alert("please select radio button");
        }        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use forloop or alerts, I want to get it working with my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You have devalued me and you haven not tried my solution...

```js
const inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
const inputEmail = document.getElementById('input-email');
const button = document.querySelector('.submit-button');
const regEx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

function confirmInput() {
  var inputCycling = document.getElementById('input-cycling').checked;
  var inputRunning = document.getElementById('input-running').checked;
  var inputSwimming = document.getElementById('input-swimming').checked;
  if (
    inputName.value.trim() !== "" &&
    regEx.test(inputEmail.value) &&
    !!form.sport.value
  ) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#342e7d';
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#979797';
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(inputName.value + ' ' + inputEmail.value);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Sign Up Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form">
      <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="name" oninput="confirmInput()">
      <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" oninput="confirmInput()">
      <div id="radio-type">
        <input type="radio" id="input-cycling" name="sport" value="cycling" oninput="confirmInput()">
        Cycling
        <input type="radio" id="input-running" name="sport" value="running" oninput="confirmInput()" >
        Running
        <input type="radio" id="input-swimming" name="sport" value="swimming" oninput="confirmInput()" >
        Swimming
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="submit-button" disabled>
        Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

With radio buttons, all the inputs have to have the same name value, so you can know if any was checked this way:

```
var valid = !!myform.mycheckboxname.value;
```

Comment: they do have the same name value currently, updating the original post with the markup